# Have whole script run, log any failures, but don't exit with a failure until the end in AIX

Tags: shell, unix, aix

So this might be a bit complicated what I'm trying to do but bear with me. I'm trying to run a script, with multiple un-nested `if` statements. The `if` statements basically determine if something exists, if it doesn't then I want it to log an error. I don't want the script to exit with an error until the end when it should show which parts of the entire script didn't succeed. If there were no errors in the entire script, I basically want it to say "Good to go" or something.

This is some of what I have so far.

```
#Checks if foo exists as a directory
if [  -d "/foo" ]; then
#foo exists as a directory
echo "foo exists"
else
  #foo does not exist
echo "foo does not exist."
exit 1
fi

#If the directory above exists create the user

id -u bar > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "bar user exists"
else
        echo "bar user doesn't exist"
exit 1
fi
```

Now that will exit if one of those gives an exit code of 1, but what I'm looking to do is to run both of them, and have the bottom of the script tell me which part failed and then exit with a 0 or 1 based of if anything failed. I've thought of writing it like

```
if [ -d /foo && -d /bar ]; 
then 
echo "All's good"
exit 0
elif  [ -d /foo ]; 
then
echo "A is fine!"
elif [ -d /bar ];
echo "B is fine"
elif [ ! -d /foo  ];
echo "A is not fine"
elif [ ! -d /bar ];
echo "B is not fine" 
fi
```

The problem is that I don't think that's very elegant and I can't just write the `if` statement like that. I've thought of using `trap` statements, nested `if` statements, and counting how many errors the script gets and assign it to a variable. Problem is, that none of those seem to be appropriate as I'd have to either code the entire thing as a `trap` and with the `if` statement I land in the same problem that I'm getting here, and the variable leads me to functionality that Linux has but AIX doesn't, which is what I'm writing it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function for it that return the number of errors:

```
check_conditions() {
   errors=0
   if  [ -d /foo ]; then
      echo "A is fine!"
   else
      echo "A is not fine"
      (( errors = errors + 1 ))
   fi
   if [ -d /bar ]; then
      echo "B is fine"
   else
      echo "B is not fine"
      (( errors = errors + 1 ))
   fi
   if [ ${errors} -eq 0 ]; then 
      echo "All's good"
   fi
   return ${errors}
}

# main
check_conditions
nr_errors=$?
if [ ${nr_errors} -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Good to go"
else
   echo "O dear, ${nr_errors} errors found"
fi
exit ${nr_errors}
```

When you have a lot or dirs, you can make another function handling the dirs or check the dirs in a loop `for dir in /foo /bar; do`.

Run the code with bash or ksh.